# KolmogorovSmirnovDistribution Normality test

Tags: java, statistics

Someone have any idea how to implement or use KolmogorovSmirnovDistribution (org.apache.commons.math3.distribution) in order to test normality for one specific distribution?

Comment: this question is probably a better fit for Cross Validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com